# Specifying properties to be updated in linq query

Tags: sql, linq

I want to be able to specify the properties to get populated/updated in the linq expression.
Something in the following fashion:

```
Proxy.UpdateEmployee(List<string> propertiesNames)
Proxy.GetEmployee() //inside the method populate only certain properties
```

The return values must be of known type(no anonymous types accepted).
DLINQ enable to select by specifying properties' names but the result is `IQueryable` interface and I'm unable to `AsEnumerable`() it in order to build the known type query afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use reflection to modify instance properties by name.
So wherever you're updating your object with LINQ you need to do something like this:

```
foreach (string propName in propertiesNames)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
    prop.SetValue(valueForProp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
Tried this approach, appears slower and produces unwanted side-effects...

Comment: What do you mean produces unwanted side effects? Slower than what? It is the only way to modify an object given the string names of the properties to modify.